# Remotely modify a running Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With most things in the NodeJS world, for example Express, I can easily call a method on the server that actually modifies the Express app. Such as... If I want to make a new route at runtime, I can just call a method I have on the server that executes some Express API methods to create a new route, and the route will just start working. No server reboot or reload.

Is there a way to do this in Rails? We could stick with the example of adding a route at runtime, or anything else presuming you understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

In some sense yes - there's nothing magical that happens during startup that prevents subsequent modification. For example if you run

```
Rails.application.routes.append do 
  get '/waffles', to: 'home#index'
end
```

from somewhere in your app then you will have added that new route. But you've only added it to that instance of the rails application. In general you'd have multiple instances of your app, so only one of them would have that route defined. You'd need some extra mechanism to ensure all the instances picked it up.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the _multiple instances_ of the running app, that usually scales with the process model.

Comment: I am 1.7 years experience in Ruby and 3 months in Rails.. Is there any post to work with you weekend ? Once I will get your reply, I will delete this comment..

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

It is possible, but it's technically complex, fragile, and depends on the server you are using to run the app. It is a very bad idea.

### longer answer

Rails applications run *inside* a server process, and the production default is to load the application files on server startup.

In theory you could use *plain old ruby* to modify the source code files in response to some HTTP request, and then fire a command to restart the application server (different servers have different interfaces).
When rebooting, the server will pickup the code changes.

This **is a bad thing**, and you **should not** do it in production.

### Alternative

It would be better to plan ahead, and think about the different alternative behaviours you want to implement. You can have some configuration data that controls the app behaviour or the routes, and modify the configuration with HTTP requests.

If you are specifically interested in dynamic routes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481458/dynamic-routes-on-runtime-in-rails) can give you some pointers.